# Invalid Host under Docker Swarm with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, docker-swarm, ojs

I am configuring Open Journal System, that uses PHPMailer, on docker swarm. I have two images, one running `php-fpm` and the other `postfix`. From the `php-fpm` I am able to access the `postfix` one using the name declared on the docker swarm configuration, and I can even telnet to the port postfix is configured (and even send emails from bash).

Nevertheless, PHPMailer is complaining with `invalid host`, when my hostname is `foo_postfix` (the name of the docker container).

What might be going on?

**Update**

Looking into the code, the hostname is validated this way
`if (filter_var('http://' . $host, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false)`
and thus, it is failing.

So, probably I just need to guarantee these docker containers have a domain? Maybe there is a default domain for docker swarm containers?

**FIX:**

Not posting this as an answer, as I do not think it makes sense. But I solved the problem by adding an alias to the container:

```
    networks:
      netName
        aliases:
          - foo.postfix
          - foo_postfix
```

This way the PHP code accepts `foo.postfix` as a domain name.